# Error sudo apt-get upgrade - apparmor

Tags: release-loki

When I do sudo apt-get upgrade in the terminal, I get at the end the following:

Errors detected during processing: apparmor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Can this error be fixed ?

Thanks in advance.

Full terminal output:

```
sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for sam:       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 gir1.2-json-1.0 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libido3-0.1-0 libllvm4.0 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libqmi-glib1 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libvala-0.34-0 linux-headers-4.10.0-32 linux-headers-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-32-generic sbsigntool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/450 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 dpkg: error processing package apparmor (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apparmor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a standard error when some process is already using dkpg or you didn't complete a update process successfully.

For a start, try to reinstall apparmor: `sudo apt install --reinstall -f apparmor`. Then edit your question if any new error appears.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for sam:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-json-1.0 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libido3-0.1-0 libllvm4.0 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libqmi-glib1 libsigc++-2.0-0v5
  libvala-0.34-0 linux-headers-4.10.0-32 linux-headers-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-32-generic sbsigntool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/450 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package apparmor (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apparmor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: You should edit your question and add this directly there, no need to create a new answer with the terminal output.